# Select File button not working in ajaxfileupload control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, jsajaxfileuploader

[image]Using AJAX 4.1.7.1213, added a ajaxFileUpload

```
<div id="UploadShapeFileButtonDiv" runat="server">
                                        <ajaxtoolkit:ajaxfileupload
                                            id="ajaxUpload"
                                            ThrobberID="MyThrobber"
                                            OnUploadComplete="ajaxUpload_OnFileUploadComplete"
                                            OnClientUploadCompleteAll="ajaxUpload_ClientUploadComplete"
                                            AllowedFileTypes="shp,dbf,shx,prj"
                                            MaximumNumberOfFiles="4"
                                            runat="server">
                                        </ajaxtoolkit:ajaxfileupload>
```

This was previously working but now, clicking the 'Select File' button which should open up a windows explorer does nothing.

If the user clicks at the very bottom of the button just before the text 'Select File' becomes highlighted with the cursor(please see image), the windows explorer popUp will open. Does anyone have any idea why this is so? I need the entire button to be clickable??

Tried google all I found was a dead end...

```
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/19353/select-file-button-not-working-in-ajaxfileupload-control[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: would there be anyway to trigger the call? which would open the windows explorer allowing the user to select the image

Comment: What do you mean by "This was previously working"? What changed?